# Formato de hora 12 para 24 em JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Tenho um relógio digital em JavaScript que está imprimindo horário de 1/12. Como converter para 13/24.

```
 <script>
    function relogio()
    {
    var d = new Date()
    var t = d.toLocaleTimeString()
    document.getElementById('relogio').innerHTML = t
    }
    setInterval(function(){relogio()},1000)
</script>
```

Está imprimindo 5:19:51 PM no horário de 17:19.

Comment: Em qual navegador? Eu fiz um teste aqui e está imprimindo no formato que você quer..

Comment: Tanto Chrome quanto Firefox, sistema MAC OS. No sistema está certo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esse método `.toLocaleTimeString()` aceita argumentos. O primeiro é o Locale (o código do país desejado, o segundo é um objeto de opções. Aí podes defenir a opção `hour12` que pode ser `true` ou `false`.

Países diferentes têm modos predefenidos diferentes, port isso vais ter de testar e defenir qual queres. [Na MDN diz assim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString):

> Whether to use 12-hour time (as opposed to 24-hour time). Possible values are `true` and `false`; **the default is locale dependent**.

Creio que `pt-PT` e `pt-BR` têm a mesma predefenição, ou seja `hour12: true` é horas em formato de 12 horas (com AM e PM).

Exemplo:

```
<script>
    function relogio(){
        var d = new Date();
        var t = d.toLocaleTimeString('pt-PT', {hour12: false});
        document.getElementById('relogio').innerHTML = t;
    }
    setInterval(relogio, 1000);
</script>
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1zf9x752/

Comment: Obrigado Sergio e Marllon Nasser.